Is it possible to cancel an approved promotion in Jenkins using the Promoted Builds plugin?
I am using the Promoted Builds plugin in Jenkins, which allows me to manually approve promotions for a build. Currently, I see the 'Approve' button to trigger a promotion. However, after approving a promotion, I want to know if there is a way to cancel or remove the approved promotion (like a 'Cancel' button).
Is there a built-in feature in the Promoted Builds plugin to achieve this? If not, are there any workarounds or extensions that could help accomplish this functionality?
I appreciate any guidance or suggestions.
I went through the Promoted Builds plugin documentation but did not find any mention of a cancellation feature for approved promotions.
